# How to create a dictionary from a nested list, when each sub-list contains two elements?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop

Given a list of lists such as:

```
[['Dog', 'Cat'], ['Fish', 'Parrot'], ['Mouse', 'Hamster']]
```

How would you write a function/for-loop (without using a list comprehension or zip)

And return a dictionary where the keys and values are the pairs:

```
{'Dog':'Cat', 'Fish':'Parrot', 'Mouse':'Hamster'}
```

Comment: Use the `dict` function

Comment: Please research the issue more before asking as this question has been answered already in so many different forms.

Comment: You should elaborate on why you don't want to use functionality that exists in the standard library or in the language itself, that would most certainly be much more effective than reinventing the wheel yourself.

Comment: This is basically the input structure the dict constructor needs, `dict([['Dog', 'Cat'], ['Fish', 'Parrot'], ['Mouse', 'Hamster']])`

Answer (score 2):

using `for` loop

```
x = [['Dog', 'Cat'], ['Fish', 'Parrot'], ['Mouse', 'Hamster']]

y = {}
for i in x:
    y[i[0]] = i[1]

print(y)
```

Using `dict-comprehension`

```
print({i[0]:i[1] for i in x})
```

Using `dict`

```
print(dict(x))
```